# How to save a perfmon Performance Counter as a textfile (Reliability and Performance Monitor Version 6.0)

Tags: performance-monitoring, perfmon

Now the file gets saved as blg, but I would like a txt version to import in Excel.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have an existing BLG file you would like to convert to CSV, you can use the command `relog` for this purpose. The format is:

```
relog -f csv input.blg -o output.csv
```

If you are talking about changing the collector to use a CSV by default, it is a setting in Perfmon itself. On the Log Files tab of your counter, you change the "log file type" to be Text File (comma delimited).

Comment: On my Windows 7 and Server 2012 machines, defaulting to CSV is an option on the **Performance Counters** tab in a drop-down list called **Log format**.